# Algebraic data type equivalent in C

Tags: c, types

I'm writing a program that reads a stream of data and parses it into some values: either integers, floats, characters, or a compound value that contains a set of values (can be nested). How could I represent that in C? I was thinking of an union of `int`, `float`, `char`, then having an array of pointers to such unions for the compound value, but that can't be nested.

Comment: Short answer - do not try this in C :)

Comment: What are you going to do with this data stream?

Comment: You could include a pointer to the next instance of the union to store a list of values.

Comment: @Pmod: Process and write to a file. (The stream is a binary file itself.) And I have already written a version that directly writes the data without storing it, but that makes processing unwieldy.

Comment: @Hamish: The more I think about it, the more I am inclined to Haskell.

Comment: And then what are you going to do with the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm imagining that you are parsing an Xml file)

We'll assume that you have a bunch of nodes.  Each node can have a value, it can be one of a set of sibling, and it could have children.   That would give you a struct like:

```
 struct Node
 {
       DATA Value;
       DATATYPE  Type;
       Node* nextSibling;
       Node* firstChild;
 };
```

`DATA` could be a union like you described, or separate variables. However, since you will reading values from it in the same form as you stored them, a union should be fine.  `DATATYPE` should be an enum.

Answer (score 1):

You mean `char` and not `char[]`? All char values can be stored in an `int`. For that matter, it's a safe bet that all the `int` values you want (and all possible `int` values on your machine) can be represented exactly by `double`.

So, I recommend a tree structure with `double` payloads in the nodes. Use an `enum` to discriminate the type, if necessary. You can represent an n-ary tree using a single child pointer and a single linked-list "next" pointer… Wikipedia has a diagram somewhere but I can't find it :v( .